# How to animate the inside height of a collapsible when I delete content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the relevant code :

```js
// Javascript
// delete formule
$('body').on('click', '.del-formule', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().remove();

    // collapsible
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById('collapsible').classList.toggle("active");
        var content = document.getElementById("content");
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    }
});
```

```css
/* CSS */
.collapsible {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.collapsible:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible.active:after {
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

What I'm trying to animate is this : [picture to show what I want to animate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epSN4.png)

So when I press the **Supprimer** button (means Delete) I want to animate the `div` getting deleted

Right now, it just deletes that `div` directly with no animation

I thought maybe if I closed and re-opened the collapsible it would animate it (that's what's in my code), but this doesnt work

Check snippet below to show the example

Thanks for any help ! :) Have a good day

```js
// collapsible
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    });
}

// add formule
$('body').on('click', '.ajout-formule', function() {

    const $formule = $('<div>').addClass('div-formule');

    const $ligne_formule = $('<div>').addClass('ligne-formule');
    const $btn_formule = $('<th>');
    const $tableau_formule = $('<table class="table tabform" id="formule">');
    const $head_formule = $('<thead>');
    const $tr_formule = $('<tr>');



    $btn_formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn spr-champs"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<button class="btn nbr-champs" type="button"><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-down"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<button class="btn list-champs" type="button"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<input type="number" name="champs" id="champs" class="form-control pull-left" value="0"/>');

    $tr_formule.append('<th><input type="text" name="titre-formule" id="titre-formule" class="form-control pull-left" /></th>');
    $tr_formule.append('<th style="width:16px;padding-bottom: 16px;"><i class="fas fa-equals"></i></th>');
    $tr_formule.append($btn_formule);

    $head_formule.append($tr_formule);
    $tableau_formule.append($head_formule);

    $ligne_formule.append('<label class="panel-heading">Introduisez la formule : </label>');
    $ligne_formule.append($tableau_formule);

    $formule.append($ligne_formule);
    $formule.append('<span id="error_formule" class="text-danger"></span>');
    $formule.append('<span id="success_formule" class="text-danger"></span>');
    $formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn ajout-champs"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> Ajouter un champ</i></button>');
    $formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn save-formule"><i class="fas fa-check-square"> Enregistrer</i></button>');
    $formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn del-formule"><i class="fas fa-trash"> Supprimer</i></button>');
    $(this).parent().find('.add-formule').append($formule);

    // collapsible
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById('collapsible').classList.toggle("active");
        var content = document.getElementById("content");
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    }
});

// delete formule
$('body').on('click', '.del-formule', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().remove();

    // METTRE A JOUR LES LISTES EN ENLEVANT LA FORMULE

    // collapsible
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById('collapsible').classList.toggle("active");
        var content = document.getElementById("content");
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    }
});
```

```css
/* Style the header with a grey background and some padding */
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header, .collapsible {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a, .panel-body button.collapsible {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo, .panel-body button.collapsible {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover, .panel-body button.collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.header a.active {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
}

.header-right {
    float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .header a, .panel-body button.collapsible {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .header-right {
        float: none;
    }
}

.contenuaccueil {
    text-align: center;
    position : absolute;
    width : 100%;
    color : black;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.background
{
    margin-top : 10%;
    margin-bottom : 10%;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.img
{
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    text-align : center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    color     : #A5A5A5;
    font-family    : "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-size    : 15px;
    font-weight    : 400;
    text-transform   : uppercase;
    text-decoration   : none;
    letter-spacing   : 3px;
}

.box
{
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.active_tab1
{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#333;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.inactive_tab1
{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #333;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.has-error
{
    border-color:#cc0000;
    background-color:#ffff99;
}

/* Styles go here */

.table-content {
    padding: 20px;
}

.form-control {
    width: 90px;
}

/* Style buttons */
.ajout-lig,.ajout-col,.ajout-graph,.ajout-formule,.save-formule,.ajout-champs, .del-formule {
    background-color: DodgerBlue; /* Blue background */
    border: none; /* Remove borders */
    color: white; /* White text */
    padding: 12px 16px; /* Some padding */
    font-size: 16px; /* Set a font size */
    cursor: pointer; /* Mouse pointer on hover */
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}

/* Darker background on mouse-over */
.ajout-lig:hover,.ajout-col:hover,.ajout-graph,.ajout-formule,.save-formule,.ajout-champs, .del-formule {
    background-color: RoyalBlue;
}

.graph, .formule {
    display: block;
    margin : 0.75%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

.add, .add-formule {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.div-graph, .div-formule {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.grad, .axe-x, .axe-y {
    width: 19.7%;
    display : initial;
}

.grad {
    width: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.collapsible {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.collapsible:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible.active:after {
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}

#previous_btn_personal_details, #btn_personal_details, .ajout-champs, .save-formule, .del-formule{
    margin-top : 2.5%;
}

.save-formule, .del-formule{
    margin-left:1%;
    float:right;
}

.operateur {
    font-family: FontAwesome, sans-serif;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.operateur::-ms-expand{
    display:none;
}

.add-formule, .div-formule{
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.div-formule{
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.center{
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Innovatech</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/38b99a3f0e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" class="collapsible" id="collapsible">Gérer les formules</button>
  <div class="form-group content" id="content">
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="ajout-formule"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> Ajouter une formule</i></button>
    <div class="panel-body add-formule">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: did you try to just experimentally use `transition: all 0.2s ease-out`  instead just `max-height` ? Just a guess, but using just `height` in transition value may be right

Comment: Doesnt seem to change anything :(

Comment: I was wondering if you can use animation to reduce height to 0. Then remove the element?

Comment: So I tried to do : ```content.style.maxHeight = 0``` and then ```$(this).parent().remove();``` but this closes the collapsible entirely, I dont really know how to do this :/

Comment: `const el = ${this).parent(); el.slideUp(300, function() { el.remove(); });` Does something like this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, you can apply animation before removing the element from DOM tree. See the below change in your code,

```
// delete formule
$('body').on('click', '.del-formule', function(event) {
var parent = $(this).parent();
parent.hide('slow', function(){ 
    parent.remove(); 
    // collapsible
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById('collapsible').classList.toggle("active");
        var content = document.getElementById("content");
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    }
});
// METTRE A JOUR LES LISTES EN ENLEVANT LA FORMULE
});
```

Here I'm using `hide` animation, same as you can also try other animations like `fadeout`.

Comment: I have a new issue though, now that I can animate that ```div``` getting deleted, if I want to add a new div via the "Ajouter une formule" button, the adding animation doesnt play anymore, I can't seem to find why this happens

Comment: It's working fine for me. Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/FgPCfk3CJGLWSruU?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention : After deleting the div first, then if I create another div, the animation doesnt play

Comment: Did you check the link? I tried adding and deleting multiple div, it works perfectly with animation.

Comment: Yup I did check the link but there is the issue there too, check this screen to explain what I mean : https://imgur.com/mSTq0xS #1,#2,#3 have all animations but not #4 :(

Comment: Okay now understood, now its the problem with creating animation.

Comment: Yes I dont understand why that happens, I tried to find a way around with $(this).parent().show but it doesn't seem to work either :/ Thank you for your time by the way I really appreciate it !

Comment: Found the reason, just move the collapsible code in delete function inside the callback, then it will work as you expected. Updated the solution and the link. Please check. Cheers!!!

Comment: Awesome !! Thank you very much ! I figured it was about the max-height not updating but I couldnt find how to update it, thanks again ! Have a good day ! :)

Answer (score 2):

I just replace your

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

with

```
$(this).parent().animate({
    height: "0px",
}, 400, () => {
     $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Is this what you want?

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

// add formule
$('body').on('click', '.ajout-formule', function() {

  const $formule = $('<div>').addClass('div-formule');

  const $ligne_formule = $('<div>').addClass('ligne-formule');
  const $btn_formule = $('<th>');
  const $tableau_formule = $('<table class="table tabform" id="formule">');
  const $head_formule = $('<thead>');
  const $tr_formule = $('<tr>');



  $btn_formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn spr-champs"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>');
  $btn_formule.append('<button class="btn nbr-champs" type="button"><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-down"></i></button>');
  $btn_formule.append('<button class="btn list-champs" type="button"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i></button>');
  $btn_formule.append('<input type="number" name="champs" id="champs" class="form-control pull-left" value="0"/>');

  $tr_formule.append('<th><input type="text" name="titre-formule" id="titre-formule" class="form-control pull-left" /></th>');
  $tr_formule.append('<th style="width:16px;padding-bottom: 16px;"><i class="fas fa-equals"></i></th>');
  $tr_formule.append($btn_formule);

  $head_formule.append($tr_formule);
  $tableau_formule.append($head_formule);

  $ligne_formule.append('<label class="panel-heading">Introduisez la formule : </label>');
  $ligne_formule.append($tableau_formule);

  $formule.append($ligne_formule);
  $formule.append('<span id="error_formule" class="text-danger"></span>');
  $formule.append('<span id="success_formule" class="text-danger"></span>');
  $formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn ajout-champs"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> Ajouter un champ</i></button>');
  $formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn save-formule"><i class="fas fa-check-square"> Enregistrer</i></button>');
  $formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn del-formule"><i class="fas fa-trash"> Supprimer</i></button>');
  $(this).parent().find('.add-formule').append($formule);

  // collapsible
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    document.getElementById('collapsible').classList.toggle("active");
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
});

// delete formule
$('body').on('click', '.del-formule', function(event) {
  //$(this).parent().remove();

  $(this).parent().animate({
    height: "0px",
  }, 400, () => {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

  // METTRE A JOUR LES LISTES EN ENLEVANT LA FORMULE
  // collapsible
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    document.getElementById('collapsible').classList.toggle("active");
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header,
.collapsible {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a,
.panel-body button.collapsible {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo,
.panel-body button.collapsible {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover,
.panel-body button.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a,
  .panel-body button.collapsible {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}

.contenuaccueil {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.background {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #A5A5A5;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.box {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.active_tab1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.inactive_tab1 {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #333;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.has-error {
  border-color: #cc0000;
  background-color: #ffff99;
}


/* Styles go here */

.table-content {
  padding: 20px;
}

.form-control {
  width: 90px;
}


/* Style buttons */

.ajout-lig,
.ajout-col,
.ajout-graph,
.ajout-formule,
.save-formule,
.ajout-champs,
.del-formule {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  /* Blue background */
  border: none;
  /* Remove borders */
  color: white;
  /* White text */
  padding: 12px 16px;
  /* Some padding */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Set a font size */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Mouse pointer on hover */
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}


/* Darker background on mouse-over */

.ajout-lig:hover,
.ajout-col:hover,
.ajout-graph,
.ajout-formule,
.save-formule,
.ajout-champs,
.del-formule {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}

.graph,
.formule {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.75%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

.add,
.add-formule {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.div-graph,
.div-formule {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.grad,
.axe-x,
.axe-y {
  width: 19.7%;
  display: initial;
}

.grad {
  width: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.collapsible {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\02795';
  /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}

#previous_btn_personal_details,
#btn_personal_details,
.ajout-champs,
.save-formule,
.del-formule {
  margin-top: 2.5%;
}

.save-formule,
.del-formule {
  margin-left: 1%;
  float: right;
}

.operateur {
  font-family: FontAwesome, sans-serif;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.operateur::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.add-formule,
.div-formule {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.div-formule {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.center {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Innovatech</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/38b99a3f0e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="collapsible" id="collapsible">Gérer les formules</button>
  <div class="form-group content" id="content">
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="ajout-formule"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> Ajouter une formule</i></button>
    <div class="panel-body add-formule">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted !! Thank you very much my friend, have a good day :)

Comment: I have a new issue though, now that I can animate that div getting deleted, if I want to add a new div via the "Ajouter une formule" button, the adding animation doesnt play anymore, I can't seem to find why this happens